# Jquery myfunction is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var widescreen = {
  "flex": "0 100%",
  "width": "100%",
  "-webkit-flex": "0 100%",
  "-moz-flex": "0 100%",
  "-ms-flex": "0 100%",  
};

jQuery.fn.MonPlugin=function() {
jQuery(".size-60").css(widescreen)
};

jQuery(".titre1").bind("click",MonPlugin);
```

I would like to use MonPlugin as function that I include on different events but console return Uncaught ReferenceError: MonPlugin is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var widescreen = {
  "flex": "0 100%",
  "width": "100%",
  "-webkit-flex": "0 100%",
  "-moz-flex": "0 100%",
  "-ms-flex": "0 100%",
};

// a plugin declared like this is added to jQueryies prototype allowing
// you to add the method to the chain of functions. but you would need to modify
// your code just a tad.

jQuery.fn.MonPlugin = function() {
  // plugins have the collection of the selected elements so loop through them all
  this.each(function(){
    // create a new jQuery object with the current element and bind your function
    jQuery(this).on('click', MonPluginCallBack );
};

// to call your plugin you would use
jQuery('.titre1').MonPlugin();


// it seems that you just want a callback function so you should use

function MonPluginCallBack( event ){
  jQuery(".size-60").css(widescreen);
}

// here you are passing the function by reference
jQuery(".titre1").bind("click", MonPluginCallBack );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, if i want to reset the css (normal value is 60%), which method you recommend ? Thanks

Comment: if you have access to the css file, I would do all the css there and simply toggle the class with javascript to trigger the different states. if you don't have access to the css you should save a variable in the parent state

Answer (score 3):

Call

```
jQuery(".titre1").bind("click",$.fn.MonPlugin);
```

instead of

```
jQuery(".titre1").bind("click",MonPlugin);
```

Answer (score 1):

Create function using this way instead :

```
var MonPlugin = function() {
  jQuery(".size-60").css( widescreen )
};
```

or

```
function MonPlugin() {
  jQuery(".size-60").css( widescreen )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`custom` `jquery` `function` or `jquery` `function` `extenders` can only be used with a `jquery object`. So in order to invoke a custom function, you need to attach it to an element.

```
$.fn.MonPlugin = function() 
{
    alert();
}

$(".titre1").bind("click",function()
{
  $(this).MonPlugin();
})
```

Example : http://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/bvtngh57/149/